# How can I add a new ACL middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm handling a client access by IP ACL.

```
function localAcl (options) {
    let {allowedMethods} = options
    if (!Array.isArray(allowedMethods)) {
        allowedMethods = []
    }
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (allowedMethods.includes(req.method)) {
            next()
        } else {
            (ipAccessControl(options))(req, res, next)
        }
    }
}

app.use('/api/v1', localAcl(options), apiV1Router)
```

The above reads a config file and decides whether to accept or not.

Now, I want to add a new middleware which reads another config file from a web file and decides the permission.

```
function newAcl () {
    ...
    switch(result) {
        case SUCCESS:
            next();
            break;
        case FAIL:
            next(new Error('Access Denied'));
            break;
    }
}
//something like this..
```

I want to check the permission with the localAcl first.

If localAcl accepts, I don't want the newAcl to be checked and the request will be handled.

If localAcl denies, I want the newAcl to check once more and if the newAcl accepts, the request should be handled.

How can I connect these two?

Comment: Set some flag property on `req` object such as `req.localAcl.isAllowed = true` in `lcoalAcl` middleware. Then, you can get `isAllowed` property value from the `newAcl` middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options

1. Use `next('route')` to skip the rest of the middleware functions
2. Handle programmatically the authorization to let the last middleware decide

The first option seems like a better option for what you're describing

> To skip the rest of the middleware functions from a router middleware
> stack, call next('route') to pass control to the next route.
>
> NOTE:
> next('route') will work only in middleware functions that were loaded
> by using the app.METHOD() or router.METHOD() functions.

[Source](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

This means that you should probably call `next('route')` in your `ipAccessControl` function.